# How do you compile a Pharo VM without an image?

Tags: virtual-machine, smalltalk, pharo

I have already cloned the VM and installed all dependencies for my platform. Now I am a bit confused because a couple of [guides](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm) suggests that Pharo image should be started to generate the C sources translated from Slang.

```
"Unix"
PharoVMBuilder buildUnix32.
"OSX"
PharoVMBuilder buildMacOSX32.
"Windows"
PharoVMBuilder buildWin32.
```

But how you generate a VM when you cannot start a VM in your platform? This sounds like chicken and egg problem.

This means is not possible to build a VM if you cannot start an image in that platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download pre-generated sources from the CI server as suggested by Esteban, you don't need the pharo-vm sources cloned from any repository. Just uncompress in a new folder and build from there.

Assuming you have your new sources in c:\phs, open directories.cmake and rename the hardcoded path as follows:

```
set(topDir "c:/phs/")
set(buildDir "c:/phs/build")
set(thirdpartyDir "${buildDir}/thirdparty")
set(platformsDir "c:/phs/platforms")
set(srcDir "c:/phs/src")
set(srcPluginsDir "${srcDir}/plugins")
set(srcVMDir "${srcDir}/vm")
set(platformName "win32")
set(targetPlatform ${platformsDir}/${platformName})
set(crossDir "${platformsDir}/Cross")
set(platformVMDir "${targetPlatform}/vm")
set(outputDir "c:/phs/results")
```

As you could not start a VM, I suppose you need to change at least the compilation flags used to generate the sources in the CI server. They are in c:\phs\build\CMakeLists.txt specially the following flags:

- -march=... (your processor architecture, search for Safe Cflags)
- Removing -g0 which suppress debug options
- Remove -O2 (optimizations)
- Remove -DNDEBUG
- Modify -DDEBUGVM=0 to -DDEBUGVM=1

and finally start the build script

```
cd /c/phs/build
bash build.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pre-generate the sources outside or take pre-generated sources from other place.

Let's assume you want to compile a kind of unix, you can download pre-generated sources from here:

https://ci.inria.fr/pharo/view/3.0-VM/job/PharoSVM/Architecture=32,Slave=vm-builder-linux/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/sources.tar.gz (for a stack vm)

https://ci.inria.fr/pharo/view/3.0-VM/job/PharoVM/Architecture=32,Slave=vm-builder-linux/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/sources.tar.gz (for a cog vm)

Comment: Unfortunately didn't worked for Windows. After running the bash build.sh script, there is a -- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    c:/builds/workspace/PharoVM/Architecture/32/Slave/vm-builder-win/cog/src/vm/
cogit.c

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: C:/pharo-sources/build
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

How can I get rid of the hardcoded path?

Comment: Can you comment once you download the sources, do you uncompress them in the pharo-vm/ folder or use the sources as replacement for the pharo-vm? Because nothing is working

Comment: Can you check the corresponding sources generated for windows? There should be a similar file under https://ci.inria.fr/pharo/view/3.0-VM/job/PharoSVM/ for the windows slave.